# can only concatenate list (not "unicode") to list

Tags: python-2.7, pypdf

I have copy pasted some Lorem Ipsum in a Word.docx file, saved it as PDF and tried to run the following script for testing purposes to extract text from a PDF.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
if (fileExtension == ".PDF"):
     pdfDoc = PdfFileReader(file(FOLDER+j, "rb"))
     fileText = ""
     print("Processing a PDF file")
     for pdfpage in range(0,pdfDoc.getNumPages()):
           fileText = fileText + pdfDoc.getPage(pdfpage).extractText()
           fileText = cleantext(fileText)
           fileText = fileText.splitlines(True)
else:
     print("PLEASE CHOOSE A .PDF FILE")
```

It raises this particular error for any PDF file. HOWEVER!, when I run the code per line, then it does seem to work. So if I first run

```
      for pdfpage in range(0,pdfDoc.getNumPages()):
           fileText = fileText + pdfDoc.getPage(pdfpage).extractText()
```

then the next line, then the last line of fileText, it works. So what happens that I cannot see?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What error is showing, what do you mean with "running the code line by line"?

Comment: Error is in the header. themiurge below has suggested an answer, but it's not complete as I want fileText to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the first page `fileText` is indeed a `list`, because that's what `splitlines` returns. When reading the second page, you add its full text to `fileText` (which is now a `list`). Hence the error: you cannot concatenate a string (`pdfDoc.getPage(pdfpage).extractText()`) to a `list`.

If you just need a list of lines, I suggest you rework your code like this:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
fileText = []
if (fileExtension == ".PDF"):
    pdfDoc = PdfFileReader(file(FOLDER+j, "rb"))
    print("Processing a PDF file")
    for pdfpage in range(0,pdfDoc.getNumPages()):
        pageText = pdfDoc.getPage(pdfpage).extractText()
        pageText = cleantext(pageText)
        fileText.append(pageText.splitlines(True))
else:
    print("PLEASE CHOOSE A .PDF FILE")
```

This stores all lines in `fileText` for later use.

By the way, when you run the code line-by-line it works because these two lines are executed outside the `for` loop:

```
fileText = cleantext(fileText)
fileText = fileText.splitlines(True)
```

This is the equivalent of what happens if you execute line-by-line as you described (notice the indentation):

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
if (fileExtension == ".PDF"):
    pdfDoc = PdfFileReader(file(FOLDER+j, "rb"))
    fileText = ""
    print("Processing a PDF file")
    for pdfpage in range(0,pdfDoc.getNumPages()):
        fileText = pdfDoc.getPage(pdfpage).extractText()
    fileText = cleantext(fileText)
    fileText = fileText.splitlines(True)
else:
    print("PLEASE CHOOSE A .PDF FILE")
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I need the fileText for other purposes afterwards. For example when I loop two directories to make this:

d.make_file(fileText, fileText2). And if I store it in fileLines, then I cannot use it like that.

Comment: What do you need to be stored in fileText? Full text or list of lines?

Comment: a list of lines for comparison purposes

Comment: Thanks to your answer I figured it out! You have to unnest it afterwards though if you want to use it in a loop 

if (fileExtension == ".pdf"):
                    fileText = list(chain.from_iterable(fileText))